# What is the sun's maximum influence on a magnetic object?

Tags: the-sun, astrophysics, magnetic-field, high-energy-astrophysics

How much magnetic repulsion could the sun's magnetic field produce on an magnetic object? Consider the object is ideal: It could be flat, to create more resistance, balanced, to stay on the opposing side of the magnetic field, for propulsion, at the right distance, not to get too hot, traveling over a sun spot, and time, during the solar maximum.

Comment: I have to say, I don't understand the premise of your question. Particularly your "How much thrust/force/etc. could the sun effect a magnetic object?" question as it is not entirely grammatically correct. Are you able to rephrase that question to make it clearer what you're trying to ask?

Comment: Now I'd have to ask, propulsion by what mechanism? Naively I'd assume you meant from the solar wind, the stream of particles constantly being blown away from the sun, or propulsion from the sun's light energy (which could propel [solar sails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail)), but you also specifically ask about magnetic objects, so that makes me think you're asking how much a charged/magnetic object could be propelled by the Sun's magnetic field. And in that case there are many conditions you'd have to ask like properties on the object being propelled.

Comment: @zephyr and this? The magnet is ideal everything, for maximums.

Comment: The problem is that magnetic repulsion depends upon the properties of *both* objects. If you have two powerful magnets they're repel (or attract) each other very strongly. If you have a powerful magnet and a weak magnet, their combined effect on each other will be lesser. But you can't just talk about the magnetic strength of one of them. You need to specify the properties (i.e., the magnetic strength) of both. Saying this other object is "ideal" isn't enough to say how strong of a magnet that object is.

Comment: fyi @Justintimeforfun questions about the Sun's magnetic field are good to ask here, and there could certainly be *slightly* magnetically polarized asteroids, but questions about any kind of propulsion for an artificial spacecraft may be better received in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @uhoh Can it be migrated?

Comment: @Justintimeforfun migration is done by moderators and they usually wait until a question is closed as off-topic before they do it but it's worth a try. If you really want to ask a question about *intentional, artificial propulsion* then Space SE is definitely the right place and Astronomy SE is the wrong place in my opinion. You can vote to close as off-topic (it doesn't hurt or look bad don't worry about that) and then also flag for moderator assistance. Alternatively you could delete here and repost there. *Why don't you flag for moderator assistance first and just ask which is the best way*

Comment: I received your flag. Are you saying you're *intending* to ask about space propulsion engineering applications? Or are you just asking a general physics question about the Sun? If it's the latter, I think it should stay here.